# Whooo is this salesforce mascot (Owl)?

Tags: trailhead

I've seen this owl character a few times, seems to be a minor mascot. Anyone know his/her name?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about general branding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hootie McOwlface, supposed to represent knowledge.

found the name on the [blog](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/02/creative-force-behind-trailhead.html)

Comment: Haha, crazy name. They need to add a fox mascot.

Comment: the name was clearly chosen by someone with a sense of humor =P